# Upload arquivo csv com ajax, json, php e Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

Estou tentando fazer um `import` de um arquivo `csv` para o `MySQL` tratando os erros com `JSon` mas não estou conseguindo, nem com um teste básico consigo retornar a mensagem, sempre cai no `else` do `if`.

Este é o form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmImportacao">                       
    <input type="file" name="demo_file" class="file-upload-ajax">
</form>
```

Esse é o script:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){       
    $('.file-upload-ajax').on('change',function(){              
        $(this).after('<span class="temp-message">Enviado...</span>');
        var formdata = new FormData($("#frmImportacao")[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/pUploadImportacaoRH.php",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            data: formdata,
            async: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.codigo == "1") {
                $("#msgInsert").html('<div class="alert alert-success fade in"><button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><i class="fa-fw fa fa-times"></i><strong>AVISO!</strong>  ' + response.mensagem + '</div>');                        
                } else {
                    $("#msgInsert").html('<div class="alert alert-danger fade in"><button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><i class="fa-fw fa fa-times"></i><strong>ATENÇÃO!</strong>  ' + response.mensagem + '</div>');
                }
            }

        });
    });     
});
```

No php está assim:

```
$retorno = array('codigo' => 1, 'mensagem' => "RETORNO");
echo json_encode($retorno);
exit();
```

Mas sempre me dá essa mensagem de erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o código de pUploadImportacaoRH.php é apenas aquele ali?

Comment: Olá @JulioHenrique, estou tentando por enquanto ver se esse script me retorna a mensagem correta, já tenha a parte do upload, mas estou testando a tentando entender esse mensagem.

Comment: certo, então coloca isso antes do echo json_encode. header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: Coloquei e está com a mesma mensagem.

Comment: muda isso: (response.codigo == "1" para isso (response.codigo == 1 . pois voce esta comparando string com numero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução para o meu problema foi resolvido da seguinte forma, seguindo algumas dicas aqui do SO, refiz o form e a forma do envio.

```
        <form id="uploadForm" action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">             
           <fieldset>
              <legend>Informe o arquivo</legend>
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Escolher arquivo</label>
                 <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input name="userImage" type="file" class="btn btn-default" />                      
                 </div>
              </div>
           </fieldset>
           <div id="msgFoto" style="padding-top:10px;"></div>
           <div class="form-actions">
              <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-12">                        
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Importar </button>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </form>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#uploadForm").on('submit', (function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax/pUploadImportacaoRH.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {

                    if (data.codigo == "1") {
                        $("#msgInsert").html('×AVISO!' + data.mensagem + '');                          
                    } else {
                        $("#msgInsert").html('×ATENÇÃO! ' + data.mensagem + '');
                    }

                },
                error: function() {
                $("#msgInsert").html('×ATENÇÃO! Ocorreu um erro ao atualizar o arquivo. Contate o suporte técnico.');
                }
            });
        }));
    });
```

Comment: @JulioHenrique, suas dicas foram excelentes, obrigado.

Comment: fecha a sua pergunta sinalizando as respostas como uteis, e marcando aquela que foi a solução (podes marcar a sua se quiseres)

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está comparando uma string com um numero, logo nunca será igual.

altere isso `if (response.codigo == "1") {` para isso `if (response.codigo == 1){`

visto que o retorno é um numero e não uma string:

```
$retorno = array('codigo' => 1, 'mensagem' => "RETORNO");
```

Caso apareça erro no cabeçalho você precisa definir o tipo do retorno, com esse código:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

deixando seu código assim:

```
$retorno = array('codigo' => 1, 'mensagem' => "RETORNO");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($retorno);
exit();
```

Comment: Rapaz, a mesma coisa, a mensagem persiste.

Comment: @adventistapr cara experimenta somente fazer o basico, ajax com o type, url e o success, ve o que da

Comment: @adventistapr foi?

Comment: Estou alterando, mas estou tendo um problema, o script do php me dá a mensagem que o arquivo file não pode ser vazio, mas ele não está vazio

Comment: mas como que da esse erro, se eu perguntei se só tem aquelas linhas no código e voce disse que sim?

Comment: Alterei o script, praticamente todo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72777/discussion-between-julio-henrique-and-adventistapr).